# findnodes could not find the given path

Tags: xml, perl

I have a simple question regarding `findnodes` in Perl. Suppose I have the following sample `XML` (`test.xml`)file as an input

```
<SquishReport version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2">
    <test name="mainTest1">
        <test name="test1">

        </test>
        <test name="test2">

        </test>
    </test>
    <test name="mainTest2">
        <test name="test3">

        </test>
        <test name="test4">

        </test>
    </test>
</SquishReport>
```

and then in Perl I want to save first test names in a list as following

```
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $file = 'test.xml';
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);
for my $entry ($xpc->findnodes('//SquishReport/test', $doc))
{
    $testCases[$count] = $entry->getAttribute('name');
    $count = $count + 1;
}
print @testCases;
print "\n";
```

But I got after running the above code I got empty List. I found out if I delete in the root node(`SquishReport`) the rest explanation, i.e.,

> version="2.1" xmlns="http://www.froglogic.com/XML2"

then every things is ok and then I have the desired output. But not in case when I have above explanation included in the main root.

Would anyone know why does it happen? Thanks!

Comment: By the way, **always** use `use strict;`. We normally omit it from answers, because it's expected to always be used.

Comment: `XML::Twig` is namespace blind, and so this sort of `findnodes` operation will work without needing to handle the namespacing. (Whether that's a bug or a feature is a different question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use warnings;
use XML::LibXML;
my $file = 'test.xml';
my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(fl => 'http://www.froglogic.com/XML2');             # <---
my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $file);
for my $entry ($xpc->findnodes('//fl:SquishReport/fl:test', $doc))   # <---
{
    $testCases[$count] = $entry->getAttribute('name');
    $count = $count + 1;
}
print @testCases;
print "\n";
```

---

Cleaned up:

```
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );

use XML::LibXML               qw( );
use XML::LibXML::XPathContext qw( );

my $qfn = 'test.xml';

my $doc = XML::LibXML->load_xml( location => $qfn );

my $xpc = XML::LibXML::XPathContext->new();
$xpc->registerNs(fl => 'http://www.froglogic.com/XML2');

my @test_cases;
for my $entry ($xpc->findnodes('//fl:SquishReport/fl:test', $doc)) {
    push @test_cases, $entry->getAttribute('name');
}

print "@testCases\n";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.